# Fast subrects from layered image

Tags: algorithm, image-processing, data-structures

I have this 2d raster upon which are layered from 1 to say 20 other 2d rasters (with random size and offset). I'm searching for fast way to access a sub-rectangle view (with random size and offset). The view should return all the layered pixels for each X and Y coordinate.

I guess this is kind of how say, GIMP or other 2d paint apps draw layers upon each other, with the exception that I want to have all the pixels upon each other, and not just projection where the top pixel hides the other ones below it.

I have met this problem and before and I still do now, spend already a lot time to search around internet and here about similar issues, but can't find any. I will describe two possible solution, both from which I'm not satisfied:

1. Have a basically 3d array of pre-allocated size. This is easy to manage but the storage wasted and memory overhead is really big. For 4k raster of say 16 slots, 4 bytes each, is like 1 GiB of memory? And in application case, most of that space will be wasted, not used.
2. My solution which I made before. Have two 2d arrays, one is with indices, the other with actual values. Each "pixel" of the first one says in which range of pixels in the second array you can find the actual pixels contributed from all layers. This is well compressed on size, but any request is bouncing between two memory regions and is a bit hassle to setup, not to mention update (a nice to have feature, but not mandatory).

So... any know-how on such kind of problem? Thank you in advance!

Forgot to add that I'm targeting self-sufficient, preferably single thread, CPU solution. The layers, will be most likely greyscale with alpha (that is, certain pixel data will not existent). Lookup operation is priority, updates like adding/removing a layer can be more slow.

Added by Mark (see comment):
In that image, if taking top-left corner of the red rectangle, a lookup should report red, green, blue and black. If the bottom-right corner is taken, it should report red and black only.

[image]

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding what you mean, with *"slots"* and *"views"* and *"layered pixels"*. I hope you don't mind, (delete it if you do), but I have added a simple diagram and hoped you could indulge me by explaining what you actually have relative to the diagram and what you actually want please? Thank you.

Comment: What I am asking is... do you just have the image or do you actually know where the corners of the blue rectangle are? Are your *"layered rasters"* solid colours like mine or are they more like photos with lots of colours? And finally, given what, what do you want to know?

Comment: @MarkSetchell I think you have understood correctly, by the look of your diagram. The actual data on each layers is not defined, could be rgba, could be greyscale. Notable is these can contain "holes", empty pixels or full alpha say. I'm going to updated a bit the question with that information. Hope it will be more clear, together with your image - thank you!

Comment: Sorry, I am still unclear. Do you just have the image, or do you know where the corners of the blue box are? And what do you want to know?

Comment: Yes, the layers data is known. Corners, size, data type and etc. I'm searching for performance - how to organize the data and how to access it.

Comment: Aha, so if I say I am interested in the top-left corner of the red box, you would expect a list of the black, blue, green and red pixels. And if I said I was interested in the bottom-right corner of the red layer, you would expect a list of just the black and the red pixels. Correct?

Comment: top-left corner -> red, green, blue, black. botom-right corner -> red, black. Yes.

Comment: So the lookup speed is critical, not the time to add a new layer? Do you also have to delete layers?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194894/discussion-between-rado-and-mark-setchell).

Comment: Sorry I can't do chat.

Answer (score 0):

1. I would store the offsets and size in a data-structure separate from the pixel-data. This way you do not jump around in the memory while you calculate the relative coordinates for each layer (or even if you can ignore some layers).
2. If you want to access single pixels or small areas rather than iterating big areas a [Quad-Tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree) might be a good idea to store your data with more local memory access while accessing pixels or areas which are near each other (in x or y direction).

Comment: It looks like your first option is what I have described in my second one? Basically, these are two arrays which you have to walk over, hence you read the first, get the coordinates, go to the second, fetch the actual data. This is what I mean by bounce. Technically, I guess thats one of the best things which can be done I suppose. Small improvement which come to mind is to have a small cache for same, or near the same regions...